# Rotating an object with a mouse

Tags: javascript, rotation

Rotation in 2D. Language: Javascript

Please tell me how to rotate the object with the mouse. I need to: click on the object with the mouse, rotate it to n degrees, release the mouse button and the object should start rotating according to where I released the mouse button.

Example implemented in 3D on Unity - [Example](https://elniablo.github.io/fizika-webgl/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to code this for you but this is the general flow of what you should get happening:

1. Add an event listener for mousedown().
2. add an event listener for mouseup().
3. When mousedown() occurs log the position of mouse.
4. when mouseup() occurs log the position of the mouse.
5. calculate the delta between positions.
6. decide how you translate that data into degrees.
7. use Animate to change to the rotation attribute of the element accordingly.